Space of functions, Banach spaces, reference books to find basic properties of Bochner integral, Laplace and Fourier transforms.
I'm looking for references where I can find definitions and basic properties of

Bochner Integral in Banach Spaces and its basic properties, such as:


Every continuous function is integrable, Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, dot (product) rule, quotient rule, chain rule for derivatives, etc.


Laplace and Fourier transform, definitions, and its properties in Banach Spaces:


Its properties, such as derivatives of this transform, or
whether it is an invertible function, proof of subjective and
injective, etc.


Am I missing something important, for someone who is starting to study evolution dynamic equations?


You can take a look at the book Vector-valued Laplace transforms and Cauchy problems by Arendt, Batty, Hieber and Neubrander. Also, for Bochner integrals there is the classic reference Functional Analysis by K. Yosida, which trates the general case of Bochner integras of Banach-valued functions on measure spaces.

@Albert Thanks for your attention and the precious references you recommended.
